# Inserting triple quotes inside of triple quotes in cson file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor, cson

I'm trying to write a some python snippets for the Atom text editor and I would like to have triple quotes inside of a multi-line body but for some reason Atom does not like that. I've tried `\\` to escape (as mentioned [here near the page](https://atom.io/packages/snippets)) but that does work either. I've left comments in the example below where I'd like to put triple quotes;

```
'.source.python':
  'Main Class':
    'prefix': 'mainclass'
    'body':"""
    class ${1:NewClass}(object):
        '$2' # I'd like triple quotes here. 
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            '$3' # Here as well.
            ${4:pass}
    """
```

Is this even possible in cson?

Answer (score 1):

This works but it doesn't totally solve the problem. So feel free to add another more correct answer.

```
'.source.python':
  'Main Class':
    'prefix': 'mainclass'
    'body':'''
    class ${1:NewClass}(object):
        """$2"""
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """$3"""
            ${4:pass}
    '''
```

Comment: What about this is not "totally" solving the problem?

Comment: In the extremely unlikely scenario where someone would need to use triple single quotes and triple double quotes in the body element.